# Trying to dynamically create a zip file causes the zip file to be corrupted

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i wrote this program for my company that dynamically makes a zip folder in their downloads. This code worked perfectly, however, when my server was updated to windows 10, when i attempt to unzip the file, I get this error.

"Cannot complete the compressed folder"

```
        string[] ProductNumberAmount = prodNumber.ToString().Split(' ');
        int amountOf = ProductNumberAmount.Count();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Clear();

            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ProductNumberAmount[0] + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".zip");


            for (int i = 0; i < amountOf;)
            {
                string productNumberList = ProductNumberAmount[i];
                productNumberList = productNumberList.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
                string s = "example text";


                File.WriteAllText(@"product_detail_" + productNumberList + ".inc", s);

                zip.AddFile(@"product_detail_" + productNumberList + ".inc");
                i++;
            }


            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
```

When viewing the zipped folder that was created in notepad, instead of the normal hex text that you would see, there is html text

Again, this exact code worked perfectly before the update so does this have something to do with the IIS server properties being changed. I have been working on this for a couple days and still have not had any luck with anything

Comment: Is it possible that you have a path contained within the files that get ZIP'd which ends up being longer than 260 characters?  https://windowsreport.com/windows-cannot-complete-the-extraction/

Comment: Unrelated, but it may help: Don't use `Response.End()` because it triggers a `ThreadAbortException` which absolutely wrecks application performance. Instead use `CompleteRequest()`.

Comment: What is the HTML you're seeing rendered to the zip file? It may be an exception message.

Comment: @Dai the html code that is being shown is my .aspx html code

Comment: @DavidTansey the path goes directly to the browers "downloaded" section and due to this, is in the local downloaded folder

Comment: And other aspx pages work on this same server?

Comment: see this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1649/why-does-iis-refuse-to-serve-asp-net-content

Comment: @LouFranco yes the aspx is on the same server

Comment: Don’t use an `.aspx` file for rendering non-HTML. Use an `.ashx` file.

Comment: You should not be using Windows 10 as a server.

Comment: Sounds to me like your code is throwing an exception somewhere after it has already set the response headers. The exception is getting caught somewhere that renders HTML. You need to either set breakpoints or add logging statements to figure out which line of code is throwing what exception specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers! It was an easier fix then anticipated. I set a breakpoint at

"Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ProductNumberAmount[0] + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".zip");"

and it threw an exception showing that there was folder that needed permission set. Once i have the user "IIS_IUSRS" full permissions in the named folder, the program worked as it originally was intended.

The reason that it probably needed full permissions was because the zipped folder would go directly into the users downloaded folder